# Push notification every day

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

How can I create a service which will push a notification at a specific time everyday? I've been trying many method on google but they did not work well. Anyone know a good way to do this? Someone say its better to use AlarmManager, while some others say its should be JobScheduler because AlarmManager is deprecated. 
Anyone have a good reference?

Comment: Use Alarm Manager to trigger notification every day at exact time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to be executed on exact time then you should use AlarmManager.

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#restrictions):

> Standard AlarmManager alarms (including setExact() and setWindow())
>   are deferred to the next maintenance window.
>
> - If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use **setAndAllowWhileIdle**() or **setExactAndAllowWhileIdle**().
> - Alarms set with setAlarmClock() continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.

You cannot trigger something at specific time using `JobScheduler`. The execution of job is under OS control. The jobs will be deferred during doze mode hence trigger at exact time won't be possible.

Use `JobScheduler` when you want to ensure that a Job must be triggered within specific interval however the execution at exact time is not crucial.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a backend server for Push notification . When Api hit request to FCM for push request with device id then device will get notification. For Automatic push from backend , use cron  from backend .A background process run in backend api and will hit FCM in some time interval and device will receive PUSH Notification.